# How to create a recursive function, that generates multiple for loops and counts the total times

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, counting

I tried to count the total number of calling times via a recursive function that generates n for-loops, but the variable seems to never change its value.

```
a=0

def recursivelooping(times,volumes):
    if times==0:
        a+=1
    else:
        for i in range(volumes):
            return recursivelooping(times-1,i)
```

The result should look more like the variable `a` below, but instead I always got a zero.

```
def multiforloop(volumes):
    a=0
    for i in range(volumes):
        for j in range(i):
            for k in range(j):
                a+=1
    print(a)
```

Comment: What is the value of times initially?

Comment: use `global a` at the beginning of the function (bad practise but solves your issue)

Comment: Global variable issue aside, your function is also returning too soon. (Since the `base` case doesn't actually return anything, the recursive cases don't either; just drop the `return` keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly having a closure maybe the shortest solution:

```py
def recursivelooping():
    a = 0
    def f(times, volumes):
        nonlocal a
        if volumes == 0:
            return a

        # Inner loop
        for t in range(times):
            for j in range(volumes):
                a+=1

        # Outer loop
        return f(times, volumes-1)
    return f

def multiforloop(times, volumes):
    a=0
    for i in range(volumes+1):
        for t in range(times):
            for j in range(i):
                a+=1
    return a

print(recursivelooping()(1, 10))
print(multiforloop(1, 10))
```

This will print `55` for both (as in n*(n+1)/2). A closure simply is a function (here `f`) accompanied by an environment (some context that maps names to variables, here `a` alone). That mean that `a` is accessible from within `f` as if it was a local variable, but it's not exactly a local variable it's a [*free variable*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names)

When you write `a += 1` the normal behavior is to look for a local variable named `a`, instead here `a` is a free variable, that's why we need to add the `nonlocal` keyword to specify this.

Comment: @Idlehands They are completely different things... using `nonlocal` you can reset the state by simple calling `recursive_closure`. With a `global` you are basically screwed, modulo manually resetting the variable. Also using `global` you simply cannot use multithreading where you have two of these functions running concurrently, but using `nonlocal` you can just "spawn" two separate counters. I often use the above idiom for `key` functions where I need to keep some state in `groupby` or similar. It simply wouldn't work using `global`.

Comment: If it's recursivelooping(2, 10),shouldn't the value be 45? since the iterative way of doing it gave the the result.

Comment: If you don't like this approach, then you can "spend" a few more lines to make this a class (with a class attribute `a`).

Comment: The recursive version iterates a different way, (3 loops instead of 2)

Comment: I posted a piece of code with two function that behave exactly the same way.

Comment: Hmm, that sum look like 1+2+3+...+10 which is 11*5=55. But I don't get why you have three loops for this in the first place. Anyway, that's beyond the point, here we should discuss this elsewhere if you need help.

Comment: def multiforloop(times, volumes):
    a=0
    for i in range(volumes):
        for j in range(i):
            for k in range(j):
                a+=1
    return a                                                                                      why did you replace the i index with times instead?

Comment: With your changed recursive code I don't know how will it do for-loops expect twice

Comment: I really struggle understanding what you need. I thought you needed 1+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+... and that's exactly what this does.